# URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration

Tags: wordpress, file-access, server-configuration

In my site i am getting problem as like following.....

Warning: getimagesize() [function.getimagesize]: URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration in /homepages/46/d390162509/htdocs/public_html/sugapps/wp-content/themes/grizzly-theme/base/shortcodes/image.php on line 89

Warning: getimagesize(http://www.sugapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/2806313447_2900756f3d_b.jpg) [function.getimagesize]: failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in /homepages/46/d390162509/htdocs/public_html/sugapps/wp-content/themes/grizzly-theme/base/shortcodes/image.php on line 89

I am trying various way but I am not succeeded . It's working locally as well but looking problem in server. Also I have no php.ini file Becaused it's sheared hoising....

If it's possible for anyone to solve this or give me any well information to solve this problem , I will pleased with you. If you want to see this problem in my site, you can visit: http://www.sugapps.com/

Answer (score 1):

I understand this error to be related to a setting in the php.ini file when allow_url_fopen and or allow_url_include is set to OFF. If it's possible for you to host the file(s) locally, that would be best. Assuming by the file path it's a theme, that shouldn't be a problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This means that the hosting company you are using has disabled this feature in php, you can not do it.  I suspect it's turned off specifically for remote files since many hosts turn that off.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. I am going to inquire with my 3rd party web provider but I also found a work around. That is have all *.php files in the same directory.